# What's the most convenient way to access Amazon's SimpleDB from Java?

Tags: java, api, amazon-simpledb

I found at least two libraries. The first one is "typica" (http://code.google.com/p/typica/), the second is the SDK that's provided by Amazon (http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/).

In the newest typica release are two quite identical packages,
com.xerox.amazonws.sdb and com.xerox.amazonws.simpledb. They share a similar naming of classes. How do they differ?

My requirements are rather simple. Nothing fancy. I don't need a JPA mapping or so. Just to get simple data into a domain and out of it with a few lines of code.

Are there more Java APIs for Amazon SimpleDB? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness, I ended up using the SDK provided by Amazon for Java. It can be found here:

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/

All other client libraries were outdated or had missing functionality.